# Call one shell script from another script and store that output of that script in a variable

Tags: linux, shell, unix

I have shell script1 `1.sh`. I have another shell script `2.sh` where I need to use the functionality of the first script and store it in a variable to use in the second script.

None of these seem to work:

```
a=$(sh 1.sh)
a=sh 1.sh
a=`sh 1.sh`
```

Comment: The first and third are correct. Please post a [mcve] that demonstrates the problem.

Comment: When `1.sh` has a function you want to use, include the code of `1.sh` with `source 1.sh` and call that function. Your code tries to assign the output of the `1.sh` script in a var, so please explain how you want to use `1.sh` in `2.sh`.

Answer (score 0):

The first solution is correct, try for example:

```
echo 'echo "hello, world"' > echohello.sh
hello=$(sh echohello.sh)
echo $hello
```

Maybe you have an error in `1.sh` or it is in a different directory? Can you call it directly by running `./1.sh`?